# Python Selenium WebDriver. How to check/verify that drop-down menu with suggested results is displayed?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

I wanna make sure that this drop-down menu with suggested results is displayed when I enter something into search field.

[image]

Here is my script (not for Google search) which doesn't work:

```
suggestions = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]')
print suggestions.get_attribute('display') # >>>None
if suggestions == "block":
    print "Suggestions are displayed!"
else:
    print "Suggestions aren't displayed!"
```

How I understand I have to check that attribute "display" is is "block". If it's "none" it means that drop-down menu isn't displayed.

HTML code of menu with suggested results:

```
<div style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 237px; top: 270px; left: 186px;" class="ac_results">
    <ul style="max-height: 180px; overflow: auto;">
        <li class="ac_even ac_over">Elen<strong>a</strong> J<strong>a</strong>mes De<strong>a</strong>n</li>
        <li class="ac_odd">Ellie portnov T<strong>a</strong>r<strong>a</strong></li>
        <li class="ac_even">Elen<strong>a</strong> Q<strong>A</strong></li>
        <li class="ac_odd">Jessy J<strong>a</strong>mes</li>
        <li class="ac_even">J<strong>a</strong>mes HotStuff De<strong>a</strong>n</li>
        <li class="ac_odd">j<strong>a</strong>mess b<strong>a</strong>g de<strong>a</strong>n</li>
        <li class="ac_even">J<strong>a</strong>mes Hotstuff De<strong>a</strong>n</li>
        <li class="ac_odd">j<strong>a</strong>mes cool De<strong>a</strong>n</li>
        <li class="ac_even">J<strong>a</strong>smin1 Gurusw<strong>a</strong>mi1</li>
        <li class="ac_odd">j<strong>a</strong>mes hotguy de<strong>a</strong>n</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My code:

```
suggestions = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]')
if suggestions.is_displayed():
    print "Suggestions are displayed!"
else:
    print "Suggestions aren't displayed!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Attribute is called `style`
2. You can use `is_displayed()` WebElement's method. It returns `True`, if element is displayed
3. You can use expected conditions. [Here's](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of) an example.
4. Your code is simply wrong.

   ```
   suggestions = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]')
   style = suggestions.get_attribute('style')
   if 'block' in style:
       print "Suggestions are displayed!"
   else:
       print "Suggestions aren't displayed!"
   ```

   This can help, but better use number 3 ;)

**UPDATE:** As it takes some time to render the needed element, it is a good practice to use waits. Info's [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html)

**UPDATE2:** You can use this code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]')),
    "Element was not displayed after 5 seconds")
```

If element's visibility is not critical you can use try-except block

Comment: Thanks a lot! Number 4 in some reason doesn't work for me. But I also tried number 2 and it works! I am learning paragraph 3. Navigation only but thank one more time!